# Client Credentials Flow With OneDrive

Tags: onedrive

Interesting does anyone build service/deamon application to manage OneDrive files with Client Credentials Authorization Flow or at least password flow.

If someone get a sample, please share.

Regards,
Dmitry

Answer (score 3):

I have been searching for examples using the "App Only" flow and came across this article describing a way to do this for the Office 365 API's so presumably it might work with One Drive as well.

[blog post about Client Credentials flow with Office 360](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/user-app-app-only-permissions-client-credentials-grant-flow-in-azure-ad-office-365-apis)

Also found this describing how to use the "Client Credentials flow", and how to setup the client side Cert to trigger it.

[Instructions on using Client Credentials Flow with Office 365 and Azure AD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/building-service-apps-in-office-365)

Based on that guide here is a [demo app](https://github.com/mattleib/o365api-as-apponly-webapp) on GitHub it referenced.

Seems the steps you need to follow are:

1. Register your app with Azure AD
2. Create and register Certificate with Azure AD
3. Authenticate using JWT ( signed with Certificate ) as Client Only Authentication

Last but not least there was another related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33755470/onedrive-for-business-api-daemon-tenant-with-app-only-token) that was answered by a member of the OneDrive dev team indicating it is indeed possible to use this method to authenticate with OneDrive.

Comment: why is this downvoted? this is literally the only documentation I could find describing this scenario.