# OneDrive for Business API - Daemon Tenant with App Only Token

Tags: azure, office365, onedrive, office365api

Is it possible to use OneDrive Business API with App Only Token for Daemon Apps?

I have tried technique [purposed in this post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/building-service-apps-in-office-365), but i couldnt access API. In fact there is nothing in OneDrive Business API documentation which indicates how to impersonate tenant users, for example `/drives/{upn}/root` or something.

Best,

Answer (score 2):

It does work with app only tokens for daemon apps. You can use the user's UPN as the drive-id, as you mentioned in your question. We're getting the documentation updated to include that this works.

Comment: Gregg: Which Application Permissions should be configured to access tenant users OneDrive for Business with read  and write permissions?

Comment: You need to request permission to all sites to have this work. In the Azure portal, this shows up as "Read and write items in all site collections"