# Error when accessing OneDrive for Business via graph API

Tags: asp.net, onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

I have built a asp.net app that successfully accesses o365 exchange with an App Only Token and Graph.  I am now trying to access a specific user's OneDrive for Business files with the same token and a Get request similar to the following:

https://mycomp-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/drives/simon@mycomp.com/items

but I get the following error:

3001000;reason='There has been an error authenticating the request.';category='invalid_client'

Any idea what is the cause of the error?

Comment: How did you create the token? Did you use the client secret or a certificate?

Comment: I created the token using a certificate.  Using the same token creation code I managed to access O365 exchange successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to do app-delegated access to OneDrive for Business today using the direct API endpoint and the Sites.ReadWrite.All app-delegated permission scope in AAD. I'd consider it more "in preview" than supported, so Yina's answer is technically correct. I'm still getting the documentation for how build an app finalized, but we'll be publishing something soon.

Andrew Connell has a good blog post about how to get this setup, available here: http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/user-app-app-only-permissions-client-credentials-grant-flow-in-azure-ad-office-365-apis

Use of the OneDrive API is possible using this same method.

Comment: This is the great post that I followed to get apponly working with Exchange Online, however when I tried to extend this demo app to work with OneDrive I get the error mentioned in the original post. Do you have a working example specifically for OneDrive that you can share?

Comment: Here's the sample I've been working on to show how this can work: https://github.com/rgregg/onedrive-app-delegate-sample

Comment: Thanks Ryan, this is exactly what I was looking for.  When you document the guide will you also explain how to configure the azure side?

Comment: Yes, I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

App Only access to a user's OneDrive is not supported via Microsoft Graph at this point in time.

Comment: Please see the answer from Ryan Gregg here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33755470/onedrive-for-business-api-daemon-tenant-with-app-only-token/33811398#33811398), he seems to claim that it is possible