# Drive Search not working in Office 365 group

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

DriveItem Search does not seem to be possible in an Office 365 group context, despite the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_search?view=odsp-graph-online) mentioning it should be supported:
`GET /groups/{group-id}/drive/root/search(q='{search-text}')`

Steps to reproduce (e.g. in the Graph Explorer):

1. create `newFileTest.docx` in the root of your GROUP folder
2. Search for the file: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{GROUP_ID}/drive/root/search(q='newFileTest.docx')` - returns 0 items
3. create `newFileTest.docx` in the root of your PERSONAL folder;
4. Search for the file: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/root/search(q='newFileTest.docx')` - returns 1 item

Happy to provide more info if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for taking the time to reply everyone! Turns out the problem is with one of my sites that I'm trying to perform a search in. Searching in the SharePoint UI also doesn't work on this site, and it's not visible in the list of Team Sites in OneDrive. A different Team Site *is* visible in this list, and searching in that Site works in both the SharePoint UI and Graph API. Will open a support ticket with Microsoft about this. Thanks again!

The affected Team Site:
[image: search not working]

The working Team Site:
[image: search working]

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the following (with my O365 group):

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/cfb5e170-36b0-4156-b17b-4b6bc2ddd777/drive/items/root/search(q='t.xlsx')
```

and it's returning one (as it should).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this is most probably due to insufficient permission. You may not have Read Write Permission for Groups.

You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54668856/accessing-all-users-one-drive-files-using-graph) .