# Drive Search not working with Client Credentials token

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

Trying to perform a [search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_search?view=odsp-graph-online) action on a Drive with a **Client Credentials** (App) token, like with the following URL:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{GROUP_ID}/drive/root/search(q='newFileTest.docx')`

... results in a 403 error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "accessDenied",
        "message": "The caller does not have permission to perform the action.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "**redacted**",
            "date": "2019-04-17T12:47:10"
        }
    }
}
```

The client has the `Files.ReadWrite.All` permisson, which is necessary to be able to execute a search query, and can read/write folders and files without any issues.

Executing the same command with **Delegated Auth** (so with a logged-in user, e.g. the [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)) works, but returns 0 results (see [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55727839/drive-search-not-working-in-office-365-group) for details).

This seems like a bug to me, but would be happy to hear if someone thinks it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that for Search to work with *Client Credentials*, the application needs to have the `Sites.ReadWrite.All` permission. The `Files.ReadWrite.All` permission is not enough, even though the documentation mentions "***One*** of the following permissions is required to call this API". Filed a Microsoft Docs [GitHub issue](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/1052).